# Count values in a list

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am stuck with lists in LUA. I have a list that contains duplicates and looks something like this:

list = {"item1","item1",item2","item3","item3"} etc 
This list is populated by the following code:

`logtable={}
if #(activity)>0 then
  for i,log in pairs(activiteit) do
    table.insert(logtable, log.createdby)
  end
end`

activity is a linked entity in my database. I have access to this through our backend interface. log.createdby is a database field that is also available through backend interface. I checked the result type of log.createdby, this is a string. So the input list is created on the fly depending on the data available.

I need to find the unique values in this list and count the occurrences of the unique values. I can't find an easy way to do so. Any hints or tips on how to do so in Lua?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the value as a key and count it:

```
local activiteit = { 
    {createdby = "item1", field2="",}, 
    {createdby = "item2", field2="",}, 
    {createdby = "item2", field2="",},
    {createdby = "item3", field2="",},
    {createdby = "item3", field2="",},
} 

local logtable = {}
for _,log in pairs(activiteit) do
    local index = log.createdby 
    logtable[index] = (logtable[index] or 0) + 1
end

for  k,v in pairs(logtable) do
     print(k,v)
end
```

console:

```
item2   2
item3   2
item1   1
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if I have a predefined list. It doesn't work if I get my data directly from the database:
`code
Res = {}
for _,v in pairs(activiteit) do
   Res[v.activiteit] = (Res[v.activiteit] or 0) + 1
end
`

also when I first create a list by looping through the database and using table.insert it returns nothing. What am I overlooking here? When I output the type of the database field it gives me back a string.

Comment: Sorry I wrote my code slightly wrong

Res = {} for _,v in pairs(activiteit) do Res[v.name] = (Res[v.name] or 0) + 1 end

Comment: If you correct the input list in the question, I'll correct the answer. it is not clear that you can not

Comment: I've added extra information to my original question, hope this makes things a bit more clear

Comment: I corrected my answer for the case when table has a nested table